# Create an advanced view with a list of contactid

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to create and advanced find view (personal view) with a list of contact ids (guids)
The guids are from another data export. I want to paste all the guids
contact equals (guid1,guid2,guid3).

The intent is to create a personal view with all these (random) contacts and run a workflow only for these contacts.

Comment: I remember I have used some browser bookmarklet in the past for such scenarios, but I could not find it now. Have to search in internet to get it again

Comment: Are you talking about including the GUID in the view columns or filtering the view results to only include the Contact records where the ID matches your random contacts?

Comment: @jasonscript Filtering random records with certain criteria. This view will later be used to run workflows with Xrmtoolbox Bulk Workflow Execution

Comment: @ShijuKunju in that case you don't need the actual GUID in the view. the XrmToolbox `Bulk Workflow Execution` plugin just uses the hidden ID column. As long as you've got Contact results, it will work fine. Just include Contact full name or any other column in your view.